# Seeding a file using Webtorrent

Tags: node.js, webtorrent

I'm trying to seed an `html` file using WebTorrent in Nodejs. I get callback from WebTorrent which indicates that the client is started seeding but when I copy-paste the hash on the client-side to download the file, nothings happened.

Here is my code on the server-side:

```
  client.seed(file, function (torrent) {
    debug('started seeding %s - %s', torrent.infoHash, torrent.files[0].name);
  });
```

What is the problem and how can I debug to see what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. It's as simple as replacing the `webtorrent` with `webtorrent-hybrid` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I think you meant "webtorrent-hybrid". See: https://npmjs.com/package/webtorrent-hybrid